# SQL MIN() as subquery - "group function not allowed"

Tags: sql, database

I'm trying to select a value which corresponds to the lowest number in another column, and then use it to SET in another table.

But it's telling me "group function is not allowed here"

is there any other way to accomplish this?

```
UPDATE team 
SET OWNERID = (SELECT USERID
         FROM teamuser
         WHERE MIN(CREATETIME) 
         AND teamId = 5) 
WHERE teamId = 5
```

(Both team and teamuser tables have a column teamId).

Comment: also, please explain your downvotes so I can get better at asking questions.

Comment: +1, There is no lower form of life than a downvoter that does not leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do

```
UPDATE team 
SET OWNERID = (SELECT USERID
         FROM TEAMUSER 
         WHERE CREATETIME = (select min(CREATETIME) from TEAMUSER)
         AND teamId = 5
)
WHERE teamId = 5
```

You can't use agreggate functions in where clause, only you can use it on selects, or in Having clause, after group by

Comment: @Gonzalo: `(select min(CREATETIME) from TEAMUSER)` - Shouldn't this condition have `AND teamId = 5` with it? The reason: it will return a min(createtime) irrespective of teamid. As a result, a createtime might come up for which there isn't a record having teamid=5. Thoughts?

Comment: that will depend on what the OP wants. It's not really clear. But the OP said that this worked perfectly, so..

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE team 
SET OWNERID = (SELECT USERID
         FROM TEAMUSER 
         WHERE CREATETIME = (SELECT MIN(CREATETIME) FROM TEAMUSER WHERE teamId = 5)
         AND teamId = 5) 
WHERE teamId = 5
```

Comment: @user1988594: No problem. I have an additional condition for which I have added comments above. Please check it as well.